# How to store the dollar ($) to a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var name = '${tokenid}';
```

im trying to assign "${tokenid}" value to name variable
but after execution the variable contains nothing

how do i resolve it

Comment: in jquery $ is a keyword..

Comment: sorry It is not clear... what are you trying to do

Comment: In jQuery `$` is a symbol (the name of a function, to be specific), not a keyword. Of course, `$` would be valid in strings even if it was a keyword.

Comment: @Prasad, chances are something is resetting the variable some time after you assign to it (that, or a scope issue). Does logging the value right after the assignment give correct results?

Comment: What do you meant by `Want to store "${tokenid}" into a variable`. Please explain by editing the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsfiddle.net/LDKsM/ — as I understand it. Probably you need to describe the problem better.

Comment: Looks like you're using a backend that pre-processes the code sent to the client. Are you using anything like Grails for example, where `$` is a special token for variable replacement? If `tokenid` variable from your controller is empty, your result is expected.

Comment: ${tokenid} is a complete string. tokenid is not a variable

Comment: are you asking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LDKsM/1/

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery. `${someValue}` is JSP expression language syntax to get the value of a bean or scripting variable with the name `someValue`. If that's resulting in an empty JavaScript string literal it's because `someValue` doesn't exist (or is itself an empty Java String) when your JSP executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the problem you encountered but here it works like charm -

```
http://jsfiddle.net/EdC9H/
```

You can put it in `single` or `double` quotes, both.